# Programmatically fill and submit QFileDialog

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

For fun, I'm writing a GUI test library. It's a good way to learn about how Qt works and could have some practical results.

So far, I try to fill all manual tasks I do at work when debugging, one of them is selecting some file(s) for processing. I want to select those files programmatically.

I create dialog like this:

```
void MainWindow::fileDialog()
{
    QString ddd = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Select file or die!");
    qDebug()<<"Selected file: "<<ddd;
}
```

When I select a file, I get selected directory as `QString`. I created this code to select file programmaticaly. The code gets the `QFileDialog` by looping over all the widgets in Qt application:

```
// Assume private QFileDialog* targetFileDialog_;
void FileDialogResult::setValue(const QVariant& var)
{
    if( var.canConvert<QString>() ) {
        targetFileDialog_->setDirectory(var.toString());
        // These two were added later, when it didn't work
        // but they didn't help in any way
        targetFileDialog_->selectFile(var.toString());
        QUrl asUrl(var.toString());
        targetFileDialog_->selectUrl(asUrl);

        QString directory = targetFileDialog_->directory().absolutePath();
        qDebug()<<"New dir: "<<directory;
        // Copied from QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory to check the real output
        qDebug()<<"Selected: "<<targetFileDialog_->selectedUrls().value(0).toString();
    }
}
```

This works, when I request it to select a path, it updates the dialog and the path will appear in the field on the bottom. It looks like this:

[image: image description]

However when I submit the dialog programmatically, which is done through this code:

```
void DialogResult::submit()
{
    targetDialog_->done(QDialog::Accepted);
}
```

Then it prints this:

```
Selected file:  ""
```

The `FileDialogResult::setValue` prints two different values:

```
New dir:  "C:/Qt"
Selected:  "file:///C:/MYSELF/programing/build-QtGuiTest-Qt_5_6_0_mingw49_32-Debug"
```

When I select path programmatically, but submit it manually, **it works**. The problem therefore might lie in the way I submit the dialog, rather than set the path.

If you want to run the full code, do `git@github.com:Darker/qt-gui-test.git` or [go to GitHub](https://github.com/Darker/qt-gui-test) (commit related to this question is `40b3e9f`).

Comment: You're using a native dialog, right? In that case, the native code drives the submission, not the Qt widget code. I.e. the dialog tells Qt code "I was submitted", not the other way. That it works when you select a path programmatically is a happy coincidence. Basically, it is never meant to be testable that way unless you resort to platform-specific code. You should also use a debug build of Qt and simply step into Qt code. You'll see exactly what's going on, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @KubaOber I understand your reasoning, but even native dialog is still wrapped in `QFileDialog` parent class and that class instance is fully under Qt's control. All I need is to tell that class to forget the real dialog and return the result I want.

Comment: Yes, and to do that you have to modify Qt, or at least inspect Qt's code by stepping into it to figure out if there's any way to hook it. The `QFileDialog` parent literally does nothing when it displays a native dialog: it uses the platform's API to display its dialog and re-enter the event loop. The locus of control is in platform code while the native dialog is being shown. That's the case on both Windows and OS X. Your code is called back on some events from the nested event loop, but all that time the `QFileDialog` is on the call stack.